Why is almond butter so much more expensive than peanut butter?
Why is almond butter so much more expensive than peanut butter?
At least this is true in the , where I've seen almond butter 2× as expensive.

What exactly are you looking for? Someone doing empirical research for your location and finding out all factors or just a theoretical answer that can explain why two goods have different prices? Also what did you researched before posting here?

Almonds grow on trees whereas peanuts grow on bushes and are underground. Apparently, this makes peanuts easier to harvest (less labour intensive) and means peanuts use less land (as large almond tress take up more space). Another potentially relevant piece of information is that almonds require a lot more water to grow (per kilogram of nuts). These are some explanatory factors on the cost side. There may be other differences in terms of processing the nuts (removing from shells etc) once harvested, but I would imagine there is not much difference in the processing into butter (roasting etc).

@smcc Interesting. You should turn your comment into an answer.
